# Segfault when freeing/deallocating buffer

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, free, memory-management

I'm having a problem when I try to deallocate a buffer.Every time I try to pass the buffer to my deallocate method, a segfault occurs. Valgrind confirmed that the segfault was located in the BufferDeallocate method.

```
==30960== Memcheck, a memory error detector                                     
==30960== Copyright (C) 2002-2011, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.       
==30960== Using Valgrind-3.7.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info     
==30960== Command: ./a.out                                                      
==30960==                                                                       
==30960== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)            
==30960==    at 0x40178A6: index (in /lib64/ld-2.15.so)                         
==30960==    by 0x4007642: expand_dynamic_string_token (in /lib64/ld-2.15.so)   
==30960==    by 0x4007EFD: _dl_map_object (in /lib64/ld-2.15.so)                
==30960==    by 0x400135D: map_doit (in /lib64/ld-2.15.so)                      
==30960==    by 0x400E345: _dl_catch_error (in /lib64/ld-2.15.so)               
==30960==    by 0x4001276: do_preload (in /lib64/ld-2.15.so)                    
==30960==    by 0x4003C11: dl_main (in /lib64/ld-2.15.so)                       
==30960==    by 0x40149A7: _dl_sysdep_start (in /lib64/ld-2.15.so)              
==30960==    by 0x40049DC: _dl_start (in /lib64/ld-2.15.so)                     
==30960==    by 0x4000BA7: ??? (in /lib64/ld-2.15.so)                           
==30960==                                                                       
==30960== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)            
==30960==    at 0x40178AB: index (in /lib64/ld-2.15.so)                         
==30960==    by 0x4007642: expand_dynamic_string_token (in /lib64/ld-2.15.so)   
==30960==    by 0x4007EFD: _dl_map_object (in /lib64/ld-2.15.so)                
==30960==    by 0x400135D: map_doit (in /lib64/ld-2.15.so)                      
==30960==    by 0x400E345: _dl_catch_error (in /lib64/ld-2.15.so)               
==30960==    by 0x4001276: do_preload (in /lib64/ld-2.15.so)                    
==30960==    by 0x4003C11: dl_main (in /lib64/ld-2.15.so)                       
==30960==    by 0x40149A7: _dl_sysdep_start (in /lib64/ld-2.15.so)              
==30960==    by 0x40049DC: _dl_start (in /lib64/ld-2.15.so)                     
==30960==    by 0x4000BA7: ??? (in /lib64/ld-2.15.so)                           
==30960==                                                                       
==30960== Thread 2:                                                             
==30960== Use of uninitialised value of size 8                                  
==30960==    at 0x400C97: bufferRead (in /home/cward/cs370/Project04/a.out)     
==30960==    by 0x4E39D95: start_thread (in /lib64/libpthread-2.15.so)          
==30960==                                                                       
==30960== Thread 1:                                                             
==30960== Invalid read of size 4                                                
==30960==    at 0x400919F: do_lookup_x (in /lib64/ld-2.15.so)                   
==30960==    by 0x4009B31: _dl_lookup_symbol_x (in /lib64/ld-2.15.so)           
==30960==    by 0x400D880: _dl_fixup (in /lib64/ld-2.15.so)                     
==30960==    by 0x4014154: _dl_runtime_resolve (in /lib64/ld-2.15.so)           
==30960==    by 0x400AAA: main (in /home/cward/cs370/Project04/a.out)           
==30960==  Address 0x6f57206f6c6c6550 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==30960==                                                                       
==30960==                                                                       
==30960== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)        
==30960==  General Protection Fault                                             
==30960==    at 0x400919F: do_lookup_x (in /lib64/ld-2.15.so)                   
==30960==    by 0x4009B31: _dl_lookup_symbol_x (in /lib64/ld-2.15.so)           
==30960==    by 0x400D880: _dl_fixup (in /lib64/ld-2.15.so)                     
==30960==    by 0x4014154: _dl_runtime_resolve (in /lib64/ld-2.15.so)           
==30960==    by 0x400AAA: main (in /home/cward/cs370/Project04/a.out)           
[boundedbuffer] Added: Hello World!                                             

[boundedbuffer] in bRead                                                        
[main] Printing from out_array:                                                 
Hello World!                                                                    

==30960==                                                                       
==30960== HEAP SUMMARY: 
==30960==     in use at exit: 1,872 bytes in 2 blocks                           
==30960==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 1 frees, 2,144 bytes allocated          
==30960==
```

I'll provide all the files so everyone can see what is going on code-wise.

Here is my BoundedBuffer.c file:

```
<snip>
```

BoundedBuffer.h

```
<snip>
```

Here is our main file, which tests the BoundedBuffer.

Main.c:

```
<snip>
```

Any advice on resolving this issue would be amazing! I'm pretty new to coding C, and Freeing/Allocing is one of the topics in C that baffles me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Main.c, you set `readParams.b = writeParams.b;` this causes an error when you try to deallocate. C's `free` method is not like C++ delete, in fact, from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/free/), as you are trying to free the same data twice  it results in *undefined behaviour*.

In other words, as both the read and write params buffers point to the same object, you should only bufferDeallocate one of them, as once the memory has been freed, you no longer have control over it and attempting to free memory you don't control is madness.